# Accessing the property file located in server location using java and spring

Tags: java, spring, java-io

I am loading my properties file using spring context property place holder as below

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-resource-not-found="true"
                           location="file://../conf/countries.properties" />
```

I want to now load this properties file in Java and am doing as below which is giving me error that file cannot be loaded. I understand that it is looking for classpath resource, but I have check the resource using file protocol.

Please advice how can I fix this issue.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                           new InputStreamReader(
                              Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                              .getResourceAsStream("countries.properties")))
```

Comment: `file:` does not indicate a classpath resource, it indicates a file system resource.

Comment: When you say you want to load this properties, do you mean you want to inject the properties into the java instance variables? Could you also add the complete error message with stacktrace?

Comment: Yes I want to know how do i access file system resource in the above code. Since I am already loading the context property,  is there a way to quickly access this in the code.

Comment: In case i dont find the resource in the mentioned file location, I have to check if the resource exist in the classpath and then load it. In loading the spring context, I can easily add one more class path in location. How could I do the same in Java code when I am getting resource as getResourceAsStream